# How to retrieve the JSON Data from localStorage like seprate email name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

```
 var testObject = { 'name': 1, 'email': 2, 'password': 3 };

 // Put the object into storage
 localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

 // Retrieve the object from storage
 var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

 console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

I want to display only email or name  how to do

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
const testObject = { 'name': 1, 'email': 2, 'password': 3 };

// Put the object into storage 
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage 
const retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

//JSON.parse first
const myObj = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
//Then access each key value separate
console.log('name: ', myObj.name);//outputs: 1
console.log('email: ', myObj.email);//outputs: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
```

and then you access name and email like the following:

```
const name = retrievedObject.name
const email = retrievedObject.email
```